# How to set custom DNS in GKE Autopilot

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-dns, autopilot

I run Composer 2 in Autopilot mode and I need to setup custom dns server for some domains in **GKE Autopilot**. In GKE Standart (non autopilot) i can simple change kube-dns configmap to add

```
stubDomains:
    {
      "domain.com": ["9.9.9.9"]
    }
```

but in Autopilot i can't change any resources in namespace kube-system.
Also I created Cloud DNS but pod doesn't resolve domain name through it.

Comment: Maybe you could get cloud-dns working if you add a DNS config to the pod trying to resolve the hostname. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-dns-config